# Implementing Stack in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, stack

I tried implementing a Stack class into VB.NET. The issue I'm having is I get an error at the line: "`Console.WriteLine(Stack1.push(item, top, maxSize, s1(top)))`"
The error reads: "`System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array`'

Thank you for any assistance, Below is the full code solution:

```
Class Stack
    Public Function isEmpty(top As Integer) As Boolean
        If top = -1 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function isFull(top As Integer, maxSize As Integer) As Boolean
        If top = maxSize Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function push(item As String, top As Integer, maxSize As Integer, ByVal ParamArray s() As String)
        If isFull(top, maxSize) = True Then
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is full")
        Else
            top += 1
            s(top) = item
        End If
        Return s(top)
    End Function

    Public Function pop(item As String, top As Integer, ByVal ParamArray s() As String)
        If isEmpty(top) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is Empty")
        Else
            item = s(top)
            top -= 1
        End If
        Return top & item
    End Function

End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim Stack1 As Stack = New Stack()
    Dim maxSize As Integer = 5
    Dim s1(maxSize) As String
    Dim top As Integer = -1
    Dim item As String = "Erica"


    Console.WriteLine(Stack1.push(item, top, maxSize, s1(top)))

End Sub
```

Comment: In case you don't know this, .NET has a [Stack class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: It looks like top = -1 so the 4th parm would be the problem.

Comment: `ParamArray` isn't the same as an array, that's the problem.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I know there is a Stack class built into the .NET framework but I'm trying to implement one to see if I can recreate it. Thanks for the advice, I will look into the 4th parm.
 
@laancelot so would I need to put just `byVal Array s() as string`?

Comment: On your declaration, get rid of `Array` (and even `ByVal` for that matter) and you should be good.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504482/5162073) to a similar question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your Stack class should have the array as a private member, and it would be initialised when you make a New Stack. Otherwise, it's a StackOperations class.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I did the changes to the code and made the function look like this -> `Public Function Push(item As String, top As Integer, maxSize As Integer, s As String)` 
For the function. `s` had to be a string because `s1` is a ordinary string and changing `string` -> `string()`leads to an error. But I gained a new error from the Push Function with the line `s(top) = item` saying `Property 'Chars' is 'ReadOnly'`

Comment: You can see the source code for the built in .net Stack class here. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,6acda10c5f8b128e

Comment: The code as presented has `s1` as an array not a string.  The `Push` method treats the 4th parm as an array.  So, the 4th parm should be either `s() as String` or perhaps `Variant`.